# XML/API cannot be retrieved by PHP/curl

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

Yeah, I'm stumped. I'm getting nothing. curl_exec is returning no content. I've tried file_get_contents, but that completely times out. I'm attempting to get an API XML from my Subsonic media server and display it on my web server (different servers). The end result would be that I can have people log in to my web server with the media server account. I can deal with the actual parsing later, but I can't even grab the XML right now. I've tried their forums, but haven't gotten much help since they're not really PHP inclined. Figure I'd ask here.

```
$url = "http://{$subserver}/rest/getUser.view?u={$username}&p={$password}&username={$username}&v=1.8.0&c={$appID}";

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

echo $result;
```

This returns nothing. The variables are defined correctly, and I get the same response as if I typed in the whole URL. Here is their API page: http://www.subsonic.org/pages/api.jsp I've even tried with their "ping" function - still empty

The url itself looks fine. In the web browser, it returns:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<subsonic-response xmlns="http://subsonic.org/restapi" status="ok" version="1.8.0">
<user username="xxxxxx" email="xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com" scrobblingEnabled="false" adminRole="true" settingsRole="true" downloadRole="true" uploadRole="true" playlistRole="true" coverArtRole="true" commentRole="true" podcastRole="true" streamRole="true" jukeboxRole="true" shareRole="true"/>
</subsonic-response>
```

I admit I've never used XML, but according to everything I've read... this should work. And it does work, with other random XML files I found on the web.

it might have something to do with the fact that it's not an ".xml" file, but a generated via url xml, as this same exact code will work with some random xml file I found ( http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml )

Any thoughts?

Comment: what this says?    var_dump(ini_get("allow_url_fopen"));

Comment: What does `curl_error($c)` have to say about it? And what does `var_dump($result);` give you. Mind you, if you _echo_ the XML as HTML, you would see exactly... nothing. Also, unless you are styling HTML, NEVER look at output in a browser, view the _source_, without all that 'user-friendly' fiddling browsers tend to do for you.

Comment: string(1) "1"
allow_url_fopen is true on the subsonic server as well.

Comment: var_dump($result): string(0) ""
curl_error($c): nothing

Comment: Okay, I found out what was wrong. The Subsonic server was operating on port 4040. I guess the PHP doesn't like communicating on it. I made it run on port 80, and it now functions.